# How to escape brackets in an ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, unicode, uri

I would like to send a GET request with only one parameter from an input form via AJAX, using `jQuery.ajax()`.

To simplify things, instead of

```
data: $("#the_form").serialize()
```

I tried to explicitly pass the value of the input:

```
function lookupSearch(val){
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "/search",
    data: {
      tx_search_pi1['sword']: val
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
      $("#results").html(data);
      console.log("Success");
    }
  });
}
```

Now this breaks because of the brackets and quotes in

```
tx_search_pi1[sword]: val
```

(which is required by the recipient of the get request)

How do I escape the brackets (and maybe also single quotes inside= correctly?

I've tried-and-errored many combinations, eg. with

- tx_search_pi1%5Bsword%5D
- encodeURIComponent("tx_kesearch_pi1[sword]")
- etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
data: $("#the_form").serialize()+'&sword='val,
```

Full Code,

```
function lookupSearch(val){
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "/search",
    data: $("#the_form").serialize()+'&sword='val,
    success: function(data)
    {
      $("#results").html(data);
      console.log("Success");
    }
  });
}
```

And if you want to pass `sword` value then use,

```
data: {'sword':val}, // get using sword key
```

As per @Urs Comment the code should be,

```
// let it is initialised before,
// and it is an object like {}, tx_search_pi1 = {key:"1",...};
function lookupSearch(val){
  tx_search_pi1['sword'] = val;
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "/search",
    data: tx_search_pi1,
    success: function(data)
    {
      $("#results").html(data);
      console.log("Success");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: And if I don't want to serialize the form, just tell .ajax: "please pass tx_search_pi1['sword']=val"?

Answer (score 1):

try putting tx_search_pi1['sword'] this in a variable and pass it.

Like

var temp = tx_search_pi1['sword'];

And pass temp

Comment: Thanks, `var temp = "tx_search_pi1['sword']";` doesn't break! Is that safe, no additional encoding needed for cross browser compatibility?